The use of articles in superlative adjectives
Superlative Adjective as a complement


She is cutest. (no article)
As a noun: She is the cutest.
As a noun: She is a cutest.


Which of the given sentences are correct?
I think no. 1 & 2 is correct but no. 3 is not. Am I right?

The OP is right that (1) and (2) are fine but (3) is not.
We use the definite article with superlative adjectives, and it's

possible to drop 'the' when the adjective is used later in the sentence, rather than directly before the noun. We can choose either 'the' or 'no article', with no change in meaning:


She is (the) most beautiful.


This café is (the) best.

Note that we can't drop the definite article 'when the adjective comes directly before the noun':

*He is fastest swimmer.

Perfect English Grammar
